# Add link in TableBlock cell

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I'm using a TableBlock in a StreamField. Rendering the page, including the table, is fine. But is there anyway to allow the user to enter a link into a table cell? Simply adding a URL has it rendered as text (as I would expect).

Does this require a custom renderer?

Answer (score 4):

Our content team had asked for this feature as well. However, it is not supported in the underlying library that `TableBlock` uses. We ended up creating a custom `StreamField` type to display lists of links, rather than trying to kluge links into `TableBlock`.

Comment: FlipperPA's answer is correct, I'm afraid. One alternative approach would be to author tables in Markdown, using one of the Markdown plugins, but this isn't a great option for less technical authors. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks, looks like we'll make do without for now.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem as well. I know this problem it is been posted a long time ago but I thought to share my solution anyway. I was giving up but then I tried to implement markdown instead as FlipperPA mentioned. And I realised that after installing [wagtail-markdown](https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail-markdown/blob/057bbb2866eb3120a2c8bf96feee361be6b51011/README.md) (please follow the instructions), I could tweak my template like this:

```
<!-- added this at the top of my template -->
{% load wagtailmarkdown %}
....
....
<!-- then in the table replace the word `linebreaksbr` with the word `markdown` -->
<table 
    class="info-list table table-responsive">
    {% if value.table.table_header %}
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {% for column in value.table.table_header %}
            {% with forloop.counter0 as col_index %}
            <th scope="col" {% cell_classname 0 col_index %}>
                {% if column.strip %}
                {% if html_renderer %}
                {{ column.strip|safe|markdown }}  <-- HERE it was {{ column.strip|safe|linebreaksbr }} -->
                {% else %}
                {{ column.strip|markdown }} <-- HERE it was {{ column.strip|linebreaksbr }} -->
                {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
            </th>
            {% endwith %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    {% endif %}
    <tbody>
        {% for row in value.table.data %}
        {% with forloop.counter0 as row_index %}
        <tr>
            {% for column in row %}
            {% with forloop.counter0 as col_index %}
            {% if first_col_is_header and forloop.first %}
            <th scope="row"
                {% cell_classname row_index col_index value.table.table_header %}>
                {% if column.strip %}
                {% if html_renderer %}
                {{ column.strip|safe|markdown }} <-- HERE it was {{ column.strip|safe|linebreaksbr }} -->
                {% else %}
                {{ column.strip|markdown }} <-- HERE it was {{ column.strip|linebreaksbr }} -->
                {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
            </th>
            {% else %}
            <td {% cell_classname row_index col_index value.table.table_header %}>
                {% if column.strip %}
                {% if html_renderer %} 
                {{ column.strip|safe|markdown }} <-- HERE it was {{ column.strip|safe|linebreaksbr }} -->
                {% else %}
                {% else %}
                {{ column.strip|markdown }} <-- HERE it was {{ column.strip|linebreaksbr }} -->
                {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
            </td>
            {% endif %}
            {% endwith %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And it will render your TableBlock in html. I hope this would help in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is pretty easy if you are OK with fact that user has to paste whole HTML of the link, not only `href` value.

You just need to pass `dict` with custom `rendered` option in `table_options` kwarg of `TableBlock`. It should look something like this:

```
TableBlock(table_options={'renderer': 'html'})
```

Check the docs:

[Wagtail](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/contrib/table_block.html) and [Handsontable](https://handsontable.com/docs/6.2.2/Options.html#renderer)

Tested on Wagtail 2.16